# Template not working with JSON / Mustache.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-templates, mustache

I am currently running into trouble with Mustache.js templates. Everything seems to be correct, and the template loads as HTML on the page. But it doesn't have access to the JSON data and I'm not quite sure why. Can anyone help out? Thanks in advance.

The Javascript that I am using is below.

```
    query.find({
        success: function(results){
        var template = $("#newCurrItem").html();


        var newContents = Mustache.to_html(template, results);
        $("#curr-list").append(newContents);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("error");
        } 

    });
```

This image shows the JSON format:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4RhO.png

And, here is the template:

```
<script id="newCurrItem" type="text/html"> 
    {{#results}}
    <!-- Template for new curriculum --> 
    <li id="curr-list-item">


            <div id="curr-item">
            <input type="checkbox" class="item-delete">
            <label id="item-content" class="item-content">{{curr}}</label>

    </div>
    </li>
    {{/results}}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

Try structuring your JSON data more like this:

```
    { "results" : [
        {
            "curr": "curr_dbc",
            "createdAt" : ...,
            "updatedAt":...
         }
     ]};
```